# Is there a design pattern for such a thing?

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

There are 2 tables: `entities` and `fields` with the relations:

```
// Entity
public function fields(): HasMany
{
  return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
}

//Field
public function entity(): BelongsTo
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Entity::class);
}
```

A field has `uuid`, `type`, `value` columns. Each field type has its own value format (e.g. string, array of strings, array of objects, etc.) with its own logic before saving the value.

I've managed to do it work with the following code:

```
foreach ($request->fields as $field) {

  if ($field['type'] == 'regular_input_field') {
    // save value as string

    $value = $field['value'];

    $entity->fields()->updateOrCreate(
      ['uuid' => $field['uuid']],
      ['value' => $value],
    );
  }

  if ($field['type'] == 'upload_images_field') {
    // some unique operations for this type of field
    // save value as array of strings
  }

  if ($field['type'] == 'select_collections_field') {
    // some unique operations for this type of field
    // save value as array of objects
  }

  // additional fields with different value types will be added during the development

}
```

Does anyone know if this situation has some design pattern solution that can be used here?

**UPD.** It seems like the strategy pattern suits this case perfectly. Thank you guys.

```
public function __construct(string $fieldType)
{
  $this->strategy = match ($fieldType) {
    'regular_input_field' => new RegularInputFieldStrategy,
    'regular_textarea_field' => new RegularTextareaFieldStrategy,
    // …
  };
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to have a look to the strategy design pattern
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: There's also [polymorphism](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) which you can leverage along with inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refactor your code with strategy design pattern.
[strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy)